# It seems I have pygame installed in Python2.7 But my default python interpreter is Python3.9 and it gives error when I run my code with Python3.9

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

So I just installed pygame by "sudo apt install python-pygame" and it seems to work only when I run my code with "python2.7 platformer.py" but gives me error that "pygame.base" wasn't found when I try to run it with "python3.9 platformer.py" and gives me same python.base not found error when I try to run it using VSCode I have however installed pygame using `python3.9 -m pip install pygame`.

[image: Using python2.7 platformer.py]

[image: Using python3.9 platformer.py]

[image: Using Visual Studio Codes Run option]

Comment: By default, there is no shared location that multiple Python installations will look for modules. `python-pygame` was likely intended to be installed where the system Python would look for it. There may be a `python3-pygame` if your Python 3 installation was also installed via `apt`, but I recommend not using your OS package manager for Python modules. Create a virtual environment, and use that environment's `pip` command to install the Python modules you need for your project.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of code and error trace. Paste it.

Answer (score 0):

We know you have installed the `pygame` package from the picture you provided, but it has some problems as it can not find `pygame.base`.

Could you try to reinstall the `pygame` with these commands?

```
pip3 uninstall pygame
pip3 install pygame
```

If it still does not work, you can try to clear the cache before install the package with these commands:

```
pip3 uninstall pygame
pip cache purge
pip3 install pygame
```